# failed to load main class manifest attribute from commons-net.jar

Tags: java, classpath

I am trying to run my java application from command prompt. while setting the class path am getting the following error message

failed to load main class manifest attribute from commons-net.jar

i have used the following command for setting the class path

```
set classpath=F:\tps\routing\commons-net-3.0.1.jar;F:\tps\routing\sqljdbc.jar;C:\ProgramFiles\Java\jdk1.5.0_11;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_11\jre;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you specify the classpath in the -cp parameter?

Like this:

java -cp %classpath%